# Unable to mount Windows shares

Tags: nautilus, cifs, gvfs

I have a few movies on a NUC in my living room and I would like to watch them in the background while I'm working here. So I made a new user on my Win 10 NUC and set everything up the way it should be, but I can't access these HDs. On my Ubuntu desktop, I enter everything correctly and get the message:

> Unable to access location. Failed to mount Windows share: Invalid argument.

[image: "Failed to mount Windows share"]

I can access the network and the computer, but I can't access the HDs.

I installed `cifs-utils`, `smbfs` and `ntsf-3g`, made no difference.

Comment: It's a server side (Windows) issue and as such off-topic here. Google is your friend if you now how to use it, i.e., search Windows not Ubuntu. If needed ask at superuser.com.

Comment: You will have to give us the error that you are getting.  It appeared that you tried to post an image of the error that didn't link.  However, please don't post a picture of the errors.  The text is always better.  The text is easier to read.  We can easily copy and paste from the text to review how others have resolved the issue.  We can't copy text from a picture.

Comment: The text is "Unable to access location. Failed to mount Windows share: Invalid argument." When I access the files on my NUC from my Windows laptop, it works perfectly. I've googled for many days and haven't found a result, that's why I made an account here and asked.

Comment: What method are you using to attempt to mount the windows shares.  Is it from the commandline or a GUI.